# Unable to invoke python shell/interactive mode in cygwin venv

Tags: python, cygwin, python-venv

I am working on some python project in windows10 and I activated the virtual environment in **cygwin terminal**.

I wrote a command

```
$which python
```

it outputs

```
/cygdrive/e/A/venv/Scripts/python
(venv)
```

I wrote

```
$ python
```

it outputs

```
(venv)
```

I tried

```
$ python -i
```

output

```
-bash: -i: command not found
(venv)
```

but the shell is not opening so I can write python commands.
How do I do that?

Comment: `which python`  with Cygwin python installed should give `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I activated the virtual environment which is in different folder that's why it gave me this path. If I deactivate the environment .it gives me "/usr/bin/python"

Comment: Can you input `type python` to see what it gives ?

Comment: it looks like you have wrong code in `python`. If `which` gives you `/cygdrive/e/A/venv/Scripts/python` then use this `/cygdrive/e/A/venv/Scripts/python` instead of `python`. OR open `/cygdrive/e/A/venv/Scripts/python` in text editor to see what you have in this file.

Comment: @Philippe it gave "python is aliased to `' "

Comment: @furas thanks. writing
`/cygdrive/e/A/venv/Scripts/python` instead of `python`
worked

Comment: That's the problem. Try this `unalias python` then your command should run fine. You need to remove that alias (maybe in $HOME/.bashrc) to avoid future problem.

Comment: corrected. Thanks